# Hadoop Job via Open PBS

Tags: java, hadoop, pbs

I am using OpenPBS to submit a Hadoop job on cluster. Everything works well when Hadoop job is completed successfully. I am using one master node and one slave node in configuration.

When i use qdel to delete Hadoop job the Java processes running on master exits normally, but the jobs on slave does not exit. The task tracker process keeps running on slave and polls for master node and gives below error message:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: <masternode>/192.168.1.17:54311. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Caught exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call to <masternode>/192.168.1.17:54311 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

The strange problem is I cannot even SSH into that particular node to kill the process manually because of the orphan job. I had to ask root user to purge the jobs.

How can I make sure that the slave process ends before ending the master process on using qdel to avoid the issue in future?

Comment: How does your job launch the processes on the sister nodes?

Comment: I am using myhadoop 0.30 and PBS script to launch processes